# How to catch unchecked transaction exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and JPA. I tried to catch unchecked exception like (Constraint Violation) which throw in transaction. Even I added catch block, it throws when it goes out of transaction boundary.

I googled and found that can be achieve by transaction callback. I tried below code: still its giving error

```
public class TransactionAspect extends TransactionSynchronizationAdapter {

    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void registerTransactionSyncrhonization() {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        // code
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush manually JPA entity manager in 
`try{
manager.flush();
}catch(ConstraintViolationException){}`. @Transactional aspect is around method 
call and you cannot catch this exception as it's flushed after method is invoked.

Comment: +1 Thanks..yeah. you are right. but is there another workaround without calling flush manually ? as I have to call it manually everywhere. I want to make it generic logic

Comment: @NFE I don't have idea but you can try extract try{}catch{} in method one level above `@Transactional` or use `@ExceptionHandler` to catch exceptions global